# What is the best day & time to ask a question on SFSE?

Tags: discussion, questions

If I have an important question whose answer is not particularly time-pressing, I'd like to know if there's a timeframe that would maximize the exposure of my question or the quality of responses from the Salesforce SE community.

Could someone with high reputation (25k+) use their site analytics privileges to query some key metrics (e.g. the days/times when most *accepted answers* are posted) and present the results to the community?

Information on the worst times to post a question might be equally valuable. I'd like to avoid having a question go "stale" because I posted during a relative lull (like this one at 1am EST--maybe??).

Comment: From what I've noticed, things get pretty quite over the weekend, but there isn't really a bad time to post questions during weekdays. Even at 1am EST, there's still a fair amount of activity on the site.

Answer (score 16):

Time of day is quite difficult to answer and our analytics won't really help you there. It probably doesn't even matter, most likely. Anyway, here are the average votes per day of the week since October 13:

```
Day Of Week      Accept Votes      Up Votes      Down Votes
Sunday                   26.5         203.3            25.6
Monday                   31.8         249.4            28.5
Tuesday                  29.4         249.9            30.1
Wednesday                30.1         227.4            25.7
Thursday                 24.9         199.2            22.1
Friday                    6.8          71.1            12.3
Saturday                  7.5          72.3            10.6
```

Comment: That's interesting that Friday is slower than Sundays. I wonder if it's because of use of GMT times (marking it as a different day that it is for the user) or because of the countries where most users are?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit old but I randomly stumbled on this post and happen to have [a query to show activity by hour of day](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/652371/activity-by-hour-of-day?MaxAge=730#graph) handy, so for this site over the past 2 years (hour is UTC):

[image]

So the best time of day to ask seems to be in the 1PM to 3PM UTC ([8-10 AM EST or 9-11 AM EDT](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?qm=1&lid=100,205,305,5&h=100&sln=13-16)) range (when the most answers are posted and the most general activity happens).

Answer (score 0):

Fridays are probably slower than Sundays because people want to get their weekend started, and focus on tasks to get them there. On Sundays, many people prepare for the week, and likely want to catch up on what they've missed since they last checked in.  Just my $0.02.  Interesting thread!