# When is the peak time for logged in users?

Tags: discussion, users

At what time (UTC) is the most amount of logged in user in Salesforce SE?

Comment: Pretty sure we can't see how many users are logged in at a given time. However, you may find this post interesting: [What is the best day & time to ask a question on SFSE?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2457/2995)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't tell exactly, but a simple query gives us some insight. We can figure out when the most activity has occurred. As it so happens, here's the most recent result for that query:

```
0  4061  
1  3639  
2  3520  
3  3509  
4  3779  
5  5635  
6  7156  
7  7876  
8  7417  
9  9159  
10 9346  
11 9216  
12 9348  
13 10433 
14 11131 
15 11259 
16 10607 
17 9963  
18 9512  
19 9011  
20 8529  
21 7468  
22 6027  
23 4815
```

With a chart:

[image: Activity by hour]

As you can see, the 13th-16th hour (GMT) are the most active, at least, but we have some sort of activity around the clock. Weekends and holidays are far slower than workdays, but you'll find that most weekdays are pretty active for about 16 hours a day, with about 8 hours where activity calms down for a while.

This is about the best answer we can give, since login/active times are not specifically tracked at a level granular enough to determine when activity happens other than things that actually happen to the database.